# Can't reflect on Private Methods

Tags: vb.net, reflection

So I created this thread: [Invoking Private / Protected Methods Via Reflection From The Same Object Instance (or Base)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744348/invoking-private-protected-methods-via-reflection-from-the-same-object-instanc/8744860#8744860)

And we got the problem fixed save for private methods. As this may not be the same issue I thought it may be best to post a different question with the full source. It is still a work in progress but it is functional.

The base class:

```vb
Public MustInherit Class BaseTransactionalSaveManager : Implements ITransactionalSaveManager

    '---- Public Properties & Backing Fields ----'

    Public Property FormDataIsValid As Boolean Implements ITransactionalSaveManager.FormDataIsValid

    '---- Private Properties & Backing Fields ----'

    Protected Property Stages As Collections.Generic.List(Of String)
    Protected Property StageCausedRollback As Containers.GenericNamedValuePair(Of String, Boolean)
    Protected Property CurrentStage As Integer

    '---- Event Declarations & Associated Methods ----'

    Public Event TransactionCancelled As EventHandler(Of CustomEventArgs.GenericSingleEventArgs(Of String)) Implements ITransactionalSaveManager.TransactionCancelled

    Public Event TransactionCompleted As EventHandler(Of CustomEventArgs.GenericSingleEventArgs(Of String)) Implements ITransactionalSaveManager.TransactionCompleted

    Public Event TransactionStagePassed As EventHandler(Of CustomEventArgs.GenericSingleEventArgs(Of String)) Implements ITransactionalSaveManager.TransactionStagePassed

    Protected Overridable Sub OnTransactionCancelled(e As CustomEventArgs.GenericSingleEventArgs(Of String)) Implements ITransactionalSaveManager.OnTransactionCancelled

        RaiseEvent TransactionCancelled(Me, e)

    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub OnTransactionCompleted(e As CustomEventArgs.GenericSingleEventArgs(Of String)) Implements ITransactionalSaveManager.OnTransactionCompleted

        RaiseEvent TransactionCompleted(Me, e)

    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub OnTransactionStagePassed(e As CustomEventArgs.GenericSingleEventArgs(Of String)) Implements ITransactionalSaveManager.OnTransactionStagePassed

        RaiseEvent TransactionStagePassed(Me, e)

    End Sub

    '---- Constructors ----'

    Public Sub New()

        Stages = New Collections.Generic.List(Of String)
        SetStages()
        CurrentStage = 0

        StageCausedRollback = New Containers.GenericNamedValuePair(Of String, Boolean)
        FormDataIsValid = True

    End Sub

    '---- Public Methods ----'

    Public Sub ProcessStage() Implements ITransactionalSaveManager.ProcessStage

        ' Use stage to fire the correct method.

        Me.GetType.InvokeMember(Stages(CurrentStage),
                                Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod Or
                                Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or
                                Reflection.BindingFlags.Public Or
                                Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance,
                                Type.DefaultBinder, Me, Nothing)

        ' Determine if the stage should cause a rollback.

        If Not StageCausedRollback.Value Then

            RollBackTransaction(StageCausedRollback.Name)
            Exit Sub

        End If

        ' Check if this stage is the last one.

        If Stages(CurrentStage) = Stages.Last Then

            OnTransactionCompleted(New CustomEventArgs.GenericSingleEventArgs(Of String)(Stages(CurrentStage)))

        Else

            OnTransactionStagePassed(New CustomEventArgs.GenericSingleEventArgs(Of String)(Stages(CurrentStage)))

        End If

    End Sub

    Public Overridable Function TryCancelTransaction() As Boolean Implements ITransactionalSaveManager.TryCancelTransaction

        OnTransactionCancelled(New CustomEventArgs.GenericSingleEventArgs(Of String)(""))
        Return True

    End Function

    '--- Protected & Overridable Methods ----'

    Protected Overridable Sub SetStages()

        Me.Stages.Add(MethodNameToString(AddressOf Me.ConfirmFormDataIsValid))

    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub RollBackTransaction(stageThatCauseRollback As String)

        OnTransactionCancelled(New CustomEventArgs.GenericSingleEventArgs(Of String)(stageThatCauseRollback))

    End Sub

    Protected Function MethodNameToString(addressOfMethod As Action) As String

        Return addressOfMethod.Method.Name

    End Function

    Private Sub ConfirmFormDataIsValid()

        StageCausedRollback.Name = MethodNameToString(AddressOf ConfirmFormDataIsValid)
        StageCausedRollback.Value = If(FormDataIsValid, True, False)

    End Sub

End Class
```

So this class is being inherited by a (so far) empty child class and ProcessStage is being called. Notice that ConfirmFormDataIsValid() sub is private. If you run this it will not find this method. If I change it to protected however it works fine.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you @vcsjones for fixing the highlighting... What did I do wrong?

Comment: Re: "Mental looking syntax highlighting". Syntax highlighter uses the tags to decide what language the code is written in. Since you had the C# tag; it was picking the C# highlighting over VB.NET. You can also explicitly say what language the code is with [an HTML comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78363/manually-specify-language-for-syntax-highlighting).

Comment: Have you considered the [Template Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) instead of reflection here?  I would bet it would be more stable. (This comment is based on this _and_ the linked question.)

Comment: Re: C# over VB.Net.... Sure isn't that always the way :) I stuck C# in there as I can read and write both so I don't mind people answering in whatever language they prefer. @ Austin Salonen - Actually that is pretty much what I am getting at, the only issue is that what needs to be called can be in any order so once the user abstracts out they can stick 20 methods in there in varying order.. I thought it may be easiest to get them to list the methods and order they wish to call them in and I will call them.

Comment: I can't seem to find a useful example, but [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stfy7tfc.aspx) article answers your question, I think, in there somewhere... It appears to be a trust/permissions issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Me.GetType.InvokeMember` (first line of ProcessStage), you need to call `Me.GetType.BaseType.InvokeMember`

You won't see private members in subclasses, even with `BindingFlags.NonPublic`.

Obviously that solution will be a bit fragile, as it depends how many levels of subclasses you have as to whether you will see the method in the BaseType or not. You might need to loop up the chain of classes until you reach a BaseType of `BaseTransactionalSaveManager` and then find the method.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just so we are on the same page, the code listed above IS the base class, does this still apply?

Comment: Yes, as "Me" refers to the type being created by the caller, not the base class that the code is actually in. If you call Me.GetType().Name from a method inside the base class, you will see it is always the name of the base class. Of course, it wouldn't be the same if you actually created an instance of the base class's type, but you have made it MustInherit, so that isn't possible.

Comment: Ah yes.. When reading again I picked up on that. Hmmm.... I may have to re engineer... Either way this fixes the problem correctly and provides the why.. Green tick for you my friend!

Answer (score 1):

This really doesn't answer your question but hopefully gives you some inspiration to use the Template Method Pattern.

First off, you're violating DRY by having the methods *and* creating a list of those method names.  Now if you do a method rename, you have to change it in 2 places.

By using the Template Method Pattern, you provide an abstract method where the child class defines all the methods they want called and in the right order (replacing the list they're providing now).  You lose all the overhead of reflecting to those methods and the developers are no longer restricted to no method parameters.

Also, if there's a good way to do something *without* reflection, it's usually a much cleaner and easier-to-understand solution.

-- CW because it's really a very long comment and doesn't answer the question at hand.

Comment: +1 I agree completely. I'm not a fan of this way, I would have just had an MustInherit on Process and have each derived instance take care of its own flow... This was orginally to hide complexity but based on dialog with my manager I may yet use your suggestion. (PS Refactor -> Rename means I only have to change it once :) )